# Number after list name

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm sure this is a really simple setting I'm having trouble finding. If I delete a web part then add it again, there is a number in brackets after the title that goes up by 1 each time. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: SharePoint adds the number in tittle, if you have same title for multiple webparts. This number cannot be seen in Webpart properties For ex: add a content editor webparts on your page, the default title is "Content Editor", try adding more than one Content Editor webpart , then you can see "Content Editor[1] and Content Editor[2]..." change the title of each webpart to get rid of number. Goto Appearence section and set chrome type as "None" if you do not want to see the Header section at all

Answer (score 7):

Just edit the web part title to remove it. If you are deleting the web part and adding it back, it sounds like it is caching the values. Typically when you add the same list view web part multiple times, it appends an instance number in brackets signifying the number of list view web parts on the page as they can't have the same title.

It sounds like a caching problem in that it thinks there is the same web part already on the page. Save the page, do a shift F5, and go back into edit mode and change the title.

It could also be that there is a list view that is closed on the page with the same title. You would need to add `?contents=1` to the end of your page url to see any web parts on the page that are closed. From there they can be deleted.

This is the behavior that surfaces when 2 web parts exist on a page with the same title.

Comment: When I go to edit web part, under appearance, the number isn't in the title.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any closed web parts on the page? Try appending contents=1 to your url and delete any closed instances of the web part.

Comment: There aren't any other closed web parts. It's the only web part on the page right now. Where exactly would I append contents=1?

Comment: To your page, so if it is https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/thesite/sitepages/page.aspx you would make it https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/thesite/sitepages/page.aspx?contents=1

Comment: It's not working. I don't know how this isn't a basic setting change.

Comment: It is a basic setting change, there has to be an instance of the list hanging around for it to keep appending a numerical value to the web part title, this is the behavior that shows in that scenario.

Comment: Thank you Eric, the ?contents=1 showed me all the webparts and there they were, deleted. I'm not sure if it helped the OP but it should be marked as answer.

Comment: The first part of this answer should just be removed; the resolution is always going to rely on going to ?contents=1; SharePoint adds the bracketed numbers itself; you can't remove them by editing the title.

Answer (score 1):

Having just been through this pain, I thought I'd expand on the answer from @Eric Alexander in the comments above to help anyone else that finds their way here via a search.

The number in square brackets increments each time you add an instance of a web part to the page.

So, say you have a document library called 'Working Docs'. 
You add it to the page, everything is fine. You add a second instance to the page, you get the incremented number.
Where it gets confusing is, if you delete both instances, then add a new instance you still get the next increment.
This is because you've not actually deleted the association, you've just removed it from the visible page.

There are two fixes.

1. The right one, as indicated by Eric above is to navigate to the web part maintenance ui. This is typically intuitive (NOT...) Go the the address bar of your browser and append ?content=1 to the URL (immediately after the .aspx). Get rid of the 'ghost' web-parts and your numbers should disappear.
2. The cludge approach is to edit the page, go to the web-part properties and, under appearance, edit the title. So, for example, in this example, you could change 'Working Docs' to 'Working Documents' The numbers then go away.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution.

1. Stay at the page that you can see "**XXX [Number]**"
2. Click the "**Page**" button at the top-left corner
3. Click the "**Edit Properties**" button
4. Click the text(possibly blue) "**Open Web Part Page in maintenance view**"
5. Check the duplicate web parts you want to remove and click the "**delete**" button above.

(If you are NOT sure which are the web parts you want to keep, please delete them all and re-add the web parts you need. Otherwise, you might end up with some white space on the web part page.)

Answer (score 0):

Click "Edit web part" and change the title. Tadah!

Answer (score 0):

Even better, you can do the above but check out this link to get more info on how to do it. It works perfectly and better than changing the name as was already mentioned.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-and-use-the-Web-Part-Maintenance-Page-eff9ce22-d04a-44dd-ae83-ac29a5e396c2

Comment: This does not qualify as an answer. Please check [answer]