# Unwanted text appearing next to Promoted Links list name

Tags: list, promoted-links

When I insert my Promoted Links into my Team Site, a number in square brackets appears to the right of the list name.  What causes this and how can I get rid of it?
I have a promoted links list called 'Quick links'
I've gone to my Team Wiki and added this list, but the title shows as 'Quick links [3]'

Comment: See this link: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151172/number-after-list-name

As said by Eric, you could simply edit the list name to remove the number and brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You may have multiple webparts on the page with the same title. Appending '?contents=1' to the end of the url would open the page in WebPart maintenance mode. Check for duplicates and delete them. You can also change the webpart's title thru properties.

Answer (score 2):

That is the default web part name - it means that the page thinks you've added 3 'Quick Links' to the page and you haven't renamed them. You could actually have 3 different webparts, or the page might be misbehaving and your other ones are kind of in limbo.

Edit the page, then edit webpart on the page. (If you are on SharePoint 2010 you don't have to edit the page first).

[image: Edit Web Part]

Open the 'Appearance' section. Change the title if you want it to show, or if you don't need it, change the 'Chrome Type' to 'None'.

[image: Change title of webpart]